# Links are not working in the search drop-down

Tags: javascript, html, css

On, clicking the links provided in the li tag no action is  being taken

Link below:
http://liveweave.com/kefdPz

Comment: where is the li tag & link?

Comment: Please explain your question & what is you "Action". Normal action for a link means on clicking that it will redirect you to specified location. And pls provide your code not something like you added earlier on http://liveweave.com/kefdPz

Comment: The tag : `code`<li><a href= "https://www.google.co.in" >Search Result Google</a></li>`code` doesn't redirect me to https://www.google.co.in/ what I want is that on clicking the Search Result, it should redirect me to https://www.google.co.in/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your's code main problem was that the `.results` was auto hiding itself before you can click on it. So, there was the necessity of few JS scripts to fix this out to accomplish both the things.

Also for some better UI you could have disabled the autocomplete in your `#gepty` search input, as you are already making an auto-suggestion for it.

I had modified your code, and made it working. I used [jQuery](https://jquery.com) and modified your scripts, added a line of css at end, removed the script and keyup `myFuction()` as I had added it on jQuery (same function, yet less line of codes, and a text message to display when no query is matched).

Here is the live bin: http://jsbin.com/facoveb/edit?html,output